# Ember raw JSON transform doesn't work as excepted?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm using the default RESTAdapter with the ActiveModelAdapter, and I want to include a **JSON object** in a particular model.
eg:

```
App.Game = DS.Model.extend(
  name: attr('string')
  options: attr('raw') # This should be a JSON object
)
```

After reading [ember-data/TRANSITION.md](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#json-transforms).
I've used the same transformer from the example:

```
App.RawTransform = DS.Transform.extend({
  deserialize: function(serialized) {
    return serialized;
  },
  serialize: function(deserialized) {
    return deserialized;
  }
});
```

When I've tried to create an *Game* instance model and save it, the *options* attribute in the POST data was "null"(string type).

```
App.GamesController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(
  actions:
    add_new: ->
      game = this.get('model')
      game.set('options', {max_time: 15, max_rounds: 5})
      game.save()
)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Before you do game.save() are you sure that property "options" is set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably you need to register your transform:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.RawTransform = DS.Transform.extend({
  deserialize: function(serialized) {
    return serialized;
  },
  serialize: function(deserialized) {
    return deserialized;
  }
});

App.initializer({
  name: "raw-transform",

  initialize: function(container, application) {
    application.register('transform:raw', App.RawTransform);      
  }
});
```

I hope it helps